# Issues with an uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception

normally I hate going to people much more seasoned than I am at a programming language and try to gut it out, but I've been scratching my head over this one for quite some time. It's the ever popular

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -
>   [__NSArrayMutable .. insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil

I'm quite new to Xcode/Obj-C, so my understanding is limited. Essentially, I've been trying to modify Apple's 'Your Second iOS App' to better understand how everything is working together. The app is basically a modified version of their "BirdSighting" app. I checked this awesome site and found no concise answers for my answer in particular.

Anyways, I have added the exception breakpoints and it is throwing at the line:

> [self.masterNewEventList addObject:event];

towards the bottom.

```
NewEventDataController.m

#import "NewEventDataController.h"
#import "NewEvent.h"

@interface NewEventDataController ()

- (void)initializeDefaultDataList;

@end

@implementation NewEventDataController

- (void)initializeDefaultDataList
{
    NSMutableArray *eventList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    self.masterNewEventList = eventList;

    NewEvent *event;

    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

    event = [[NewEvent alloc] initWithName:@"Event" date:today];

    [self addNewEventWithEvent:event];
}

- (void)setMasterNewEventList:(NSMutableArray *)newList
{
    if (_masterNewEventList != newList)
        _masterNewEventList = [newList mutableCopy];
}

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        [self initializeDefaultDataList];

        return self;
    }

    return nil;
}

- (NSUInteger)countOfList
{
    return [self.masterNewEventList count];
}

- (NewEvent *)objectInListAtIndex:(NSUInteger)theIndex
{
    return [self.masterNewEventList objectAtIndex:theIndex];
}

- (void)addNewEventWithEvent:(NewEvent *)event
{
    [self.masterNewEventList addObject:event];
}

@end
```

My NewEvent.m is as follows:

```
#import "NewEvent.h"

@implementation NewEvent

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)event date:(NSDate *)date
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        _event = event;

        _date = date;

        return self;

    }

    return nil;
}

@end
```

My line of thinking is that when it is trying to add the initial event (right before throwing), the event itself is not initialized properly. The debug reads:

```
event = (NewEvent *) 0x00000000
```

Thanks in advance for taking a look.

```
main.m 

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "ParentAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([ParentAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your table view delegate method to sort your problem UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your  initWithName:date method of your NewEvent class you need to return self in your if block.  In your case, after this method runs you are always returning nil.

Like this:

```
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)event date:(NSDate *)date
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        _event = event;

        _date = date;        
        //don't forget this line
        return self;
     }
     return nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems to have fixed that issue, but apparently the program is further flawed.

Comment: @Allen Shultz No problem!  Try to work through your code and ask a new question if you need to

Comment: Now, it is still throwing, but with this error "UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:" but what is weird is that the only section mentioned "forIndexPath" in my code is commented out. I don't understand that.

Comment: In addition, the exception breakpoints from before now go all the way back to main.m where the only code is included in the question edit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your init method.You should return self in it.

```
 - (id)initWithName:(NSString *)event date:(NSDate *)date
    {
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        _event = event;
        _date = date; 
        return self;
    }

    return nil;
}
```